# How do I go about updating all relative records with my linq instead of first or default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In order to update my records with my checkout link I passed the query string `unum` through an `Html.ActionLink`, then call it in my `ActionResult`.

```
public ActionResult Checkout(Order order, int ? unum)
{            
    order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => unum == o.OrderNum);
    order.RecievedShirt = false;
    order.OrderCompleted = true;
    db.SaveChanges();

    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Purchased", "Orders");        
}
```

While this works it only updates the first record. How do I update them all?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` returns only the first match. Use a `.Where()` to get a collection of all matches and use a loop to update (and can the value of `OrderNum` be `null`?)

Comment: And why do you have a parameter `Order order` when you then over write it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am just trying to make sense of what I am reading and learning. I am not by no means a pro...yet :)

Comment: Just remove the `Order order` parameter and I suspect that it should be `int unum` (not nullable)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I removed it. I understood what you were saying shortly after I comented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FirstOrDefault` method returns the first element matching the where condition. If you want all records matching the condition,Use `Where` method to get all orders matching that `unum` (assuming you have more than one orders matching `OrderNum` value with `unum` variable value)  and udpate the property values inside a loop.

Also there is no need of the Order parameter in the action method as you are getting orders matching your where condition.

```
public ActionResult Checkout(int? unum)
{            
    if(unum!=null)
    {
      var allOrders = db.Orders.Where(o =>  o.OrderNum==unum.Value);
      foreach(var order in allOrders)
      {
         order.RecievedShirt = false;
         order.OrderCompleted = true;
      }
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
    //to do : Do something if unum is null ????? 
    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Purchased", "Orders");        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also providing the explanation